# When I run my GB model I get "TypeError: object of type 'CategoricalDtype' has no len()", what does this mean and how can i fix it?

Tags: python, gaussian, naivebayes

I want to run a gaussian model on my dataset that i had to bin into categories. Now that I run the code I recieve the error: TypeError: object of type 'CategoricalDtype' has no len()

Not sure what this means or how I can fix it so that my model runs.

I want to fix this errror so that I can run my naive model efficiently.[

[image: Dataset and dtypes]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your code, but len() is short for length. It seems like you're passing a categorical dataset to something that expects something that has a length, which a `CategoricalDType` doesn't have, apparently.